# abstract functions in python without using lambda

Tags: python, abstraction

I just have a question. how to use abstract functions without lambda?

say I have two list

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,4,6]
```

if I want to print all the elements both appear in A and B,

with lambda:

```
def f():
  print reduce (list.__add__ , map (lambda x: filter (lambda y: x == y, b), a))
```

how to do it without lambda?

i mean i'm just using helper functions instead of lambda

Comment: Why do you not want to use lambda?

Comment: I thinks you mean **anonymous functions**

Comment: What do you mean by "abstract functions"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you get the intersection of two sets?  If you use the `set` data type, you can just use `&` for union:

```
print list(set(a) & set(b))
```

Comment: Or (slightly) more efficiently:  `set(a).intersection(b)`

Comment: @mgilson: I don't doubt that it's more efficient, but it's not as symmetrical :-P

Comment: It's a useful idiom to know though since `b` can be any iterable (think generator).  With your version, you need to store both sets in memory, but with my version you only need 1.

Comment: Also, you're looking for the *intersection* of 2 lists which is different than the *union*

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [2,4,6]
ab = []

for i in a:
  if i in b:
    ab.append(i)
print(ab)
```

Comment: +1 this works for duplicates (although is inefficient if a and b are larger)

Comment: yeah, I just assumed this was a homework type question and wasn't going to be used for very large data.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Counter if there is risk of **duplicates**:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 2, 3]
>>> b = [2, 2, 3]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(a) & Counter(b)
Counter({2: 2, 3: 1})
>>>

>>> list_ = []
>>> c = Counter(a) & Counter(b)
>>> for num, count in c.items():
...     list_.extend([num] * count)
...
>>> list_
[2, 2, 3]
```